# Data Visulation Problem With Bar Plot and It's axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphics, seaborn

i have a problem. I will show it you with pictures and tables.

```
            0
MGROS   4.983566
SOKM    4.983566
BIMAS   4.983566
POLHO   4.043808
VESBE   2.722698
ARCLK   2.722698
VESTL   2.722698
HURGZ   2.125138
YATAS   2.030432
SELEC   1.986755
```

My dataframe is like above and graph is like below.
[image: Graph]

```
# creating the bar plot
br = plt.bar(df.index, df.values.squeeze(), color =colorLIST,
        width = 0.9)
#for rect in br:
#    height = rect.get_height()
#    plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.0, height, "%"+f'{height:.2f}', ha='center',         va='bottom', color = "#003C5F", fontsize = 5.5)
plt.xlabel("Sembol", color = "#7F2A3C", fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel("Getiri", color = "#7F2A3C", fontsize = 20)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90, fontsize = 20 )
labels = plt.gca().get_xticklabels()
for i in range(len(labels)):
    labels[i].set_color(colorLIST[i])
plt.title("Global Sektörler", color = "#7F2A3C", fontsize = 20)

ax.spines['top'].set_color('#C2B280')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
#ax.grid(zorder=0)
#ax.xaxis.grid()
minor_locator = AutoMinorLocator(2)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
plt.grid(which='minor')
plt.savefig("peers_company.png", dpi = 100)
plt.show()
```

The code is above. I want to show the same values in one bar. For example, MGROS, SOKM and BIMAS same values. How can i show it one bar and one xticks as with all three names one under the other?

Comment: this is a data prep problem. i wouldn't try to solve this in the visualization itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. Here is the code.

I only rearranged my dataframe.

```
df['marker'] = (df[0] != df[0].shift()).cumsum()
df["TICKERS"] = df.index.tolist()
df = df.groupby('marker').agg({ 0: "first", "TICKERS": lambda x: list(x)})
df["VALUES"] = df[0].values
df.TICKERS = df.TICKERS.apply(lambda x : " ".join(x))
```